# Why is my ALTER SYSTEM command failing here?

Tags: sql, oracle

A colleague gave me some code to run. I need to set the archive log location to a directory inside `db_recovery_file_dest`   . I am using a VirtualBox VM , called "Oracle Developer Days"

I'm trying to run the following command :

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET log_archive_dest_1 = '/home' SCOPE=both;
```

But it's generating this error :

```
SQL> ALTER SYSTEM SET log_archive_dest_1 = '/home' SCOPE=both;
ALTER SYSTEM SET log_archive_dest_1 = '/home' SCOPE=both
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-32017: failure in updating SPFILE
ORA-16179: incremental changes to "log_archive_dest_1" not allowed with SPFILE


SQL>
```

What is the SPFILE ?

Also , could the problem be that I'm using a Virtual Machine ?

Comment: Is the syntax correct?  Shouldn't there be a comma or something before `SCOPE`?

Comment: @wallyk - hmm, a comma ?

Comment: You can use `='LOCATION=/home'`

Comment: Shouldn't you use location variable to log_archive_dest_1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is `ALTER SYSTEM SET log_archive_dest_1 = 'LOCATION=/home' SCOPE=both;`.  It's in the docs: [find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-16741F21-B0A4-4408-9A9D-75A87C7EF7C0.htm#ADMQS12432).

You shouldn't be setting it to `/home`.  I hope that's a just a simplification you've made for posting here.

> "What is the SPFILE ?"

You need to understand what you're doing.  Please read the documentation and learn some basic concepts about the Oracle database and being a DBA.  [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-EFF3CCE9-DD06-4755-B2DA-32CDD26F7A18.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Which Oracle version are you using?

SPFILE stands for Server Parameter File (called PFILE prior to 9i release) it contains some parameters which is used by Oracle to initialize certain variables at the time when database is brought up.

You can use the below mentioned query to check where your server parameter (SPFILE) is stored.

```
show parameter spfile
```

Regards
Andy